# restbed library issues error for request->get_header when running code in documentation

Tags: c++

I was trying to run the example in the readme for Restbed and this line

```
request->get_header("Content-Type", 0);
```

seemed to issue the following error:

```
more than one instance of overloaded function "restbed::Request::get_header" matches the argument list:

function "restbed::Request::get_header(const std::string &name, const std::string &default_value = "") const" (declared at line 101 of "/usr/include/corvusoft/restbed/request.hpp") -- 

function "restbed::Request::get_header(const std::string &name, const std::function<std::string (const std::string &)> &transform) const" (declared at line 103 of usr/include/corvusoft/restbed/request.hpp")
```

I was wondering why that is and how to resolve this. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue when installing via Linux command line. I had project that previously used restbed on a different computer and found it no longer ran due to this exact error.
The following solved it for me.

Start by removing your current install.

```
sudo apt remove librestbed-dev.
```

Then do the following(you can do it in the home directory)

Download the source code:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/corvusorft/restbed.git
```

(OR)
Download the files https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/archive/master.zip

```
mkdir restbed/build

cd restbed/build

cmake [-DBUILD_SSL=NO] ..
```

If this command above does not work try changing directory to restbed then run the step 4 command.

```
make install

make test
```

If you are having troubles with this step try running `make install` again then run make tests. For some reason this fixed the issue I was having.

Copy (or move) the header and library files to the appropriate location

From the restbed directory:

`cp -r distribution/include/* /usr/local/include` will move the header files to your local include directory, which g++ knows to look in for headers

`cp -a distribution/library/* /usr/local/lib` will move the library file to your local library directory, which, again, g++ knows to look in for libraries

Final Step:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```